# Drawing an equiangular spiral between two known points in Julia

Tags: math, plot, julia, spiral

I have two random points in a 2D Cartesian grid, `p1` and `p2`. I would like to define a curve between `p1` and `p2` of N points such that the curve forms an equiangular spiral (similar to what is done in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/journal/Evolutionary-Intelligence-1864-5917/publication/331328734_Emperor_Penguins_Colony_a_new_metaheuristic_algorithm_for_optimization/links/5fc1e3f7299bf104cf87a2dd/Emperor-Penguins-Colony-a-new-metaheuristic-algorithm-for-optimization.pdf?_sg%5B0%5D=f6e2pQCPm0BwHI1NgbvXeQKMbOIfNmmtJS8-icWBj7HpFlOSQkCEr6yJONyiJb77wKI566zhUo8hnQ-bZujdoA.Js3WPOKWeuMEYmLRb17h5fHrSt3nB34zmjbfiOAYXDmCl_DHIpJUpOgLFnpz7XeHraxjqRNEjxA0ZCUOXOrozg&_sg%5B1%5D=4JeXAnYBhcqKXrldl3lmP3R6HINxQvrfdMl6iVQJ2LJKOFLQaRfRGaSjx5VJcWaYx8vQP6Cg4QO2d_8S88tOtiH-KR4l5mLID0N0J_RSCHP-.Js3WPOKWeuMEYmLRb17h5fHrSt3nB34zmjbfiOAYXDmCl_DHIpJUpOgLFnpz7XeHraxjqRNEjxA0ZCUOXOrozg&_iepl=) paper (Fig. 8)). I've tried converting the paper into a script, but something is still off, so I'm trying to build a "dumbed down" example. My closest attempt is this (`p2` can be seen on zoom-in, but not shown in script's plot):

```
using PyPlot
using LinearAlgebra
p1 = [5,7]
p2 = [1,2]
r = norm(p1-p2)
theta_offset = tan((p1[2]-p2[2])/(p1[1]-p2[1]));
# Number of points
rez = 500
# Number of revolutions
rev = 5
# Radius as spiral decreases
t = range(0,r,rez)
# Angle as spiral decreases
theta = range(0, 2*pi*rev, rez) .+ theta_offset
x = cos.(theta).*exp.(-t).+p2[1];
y = sin.(theta).*exp.(-t).+p2[2];

figure()
plot(x,y)
scatter(p1[1],p1[2],c="red",s=5)
scatter(p2[1],p2[2],c="red",s=10)
show(); gcf()
```

which produces the following plot:
[image]

While the plot is centered on `p2` (at coordinate [1,2]), the endpoint does not lie near / pass through my specified point `p1`. My ideal outcome would be something like this:
[image: ![enter image description here]

EDIT: Solved problem using @PaSTE's suggestion. Changing my `theta_offset`, `x`, and `y` coordinate calculations to:

```
theta_offset = atan((p1[2]-p2[2])/(p1[1]-p2[1]));
x = cos.(theta).*exp.(-t).*r.+p2[1]
y = sin.(theta).*exp.(-t).*r.+p2[2]
```

yields the following plot, exactly what I was hoping for. In my solution, handedness and number of loops are not important.
[image]

Comment: where are p1 and p2 in your script's plot? (and that's not a request for a comment to answer that: we know where they are, so please update your script and your post so that your image has both of them in there, instead of a cropped graph that can't even show p1 =)

Comment: In your implementation, it looks like you use `tan` when you mean `atan` when defining `theta_offset`. Additionally, the `x` and `y` values can only take values from `p2 .- 1` to `p2 .+ 1`. As Pomax suggests, consider using the `r` you calculate to scale the values you add to `p2`, and you'll get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @PaSTE, that works beautifully, thank you! If you'd like to formalize or separate your answer, I'd be happy to give you credit for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As PaSTE said, The issue is the algebra: you need get the angle with atan, not tan, and multiply your exponential factor by r to get the right radius.

```
using LinearAlgebra
using Plots

p1 = [5,7]
p2 = [1,2]
r = norm(p1-p2)
theta_offset = atan((p1[2]-p2[2])/(p1[1]-p2[1]));
# Number of points
rez = 1500
# Number of revolutions
rev = 5
# Radius as spiral decreases
t = range(0,r,rez)
# Angle as spiral decreases
theta = range(0, 2*pi*rev, rez) .+ theta_offset
x = cos.(theta) .* r .* exp.(-t) .+ p2[1]
y = sin.(theta) .* r .* exp.(-t) .+ p2[2]
plot(x, y)
scatter!([p1[1], p2[1]], [p1[2], p2[2]])
```

Comment: Just for the (late) record here.